# Binding collection of images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with my program "SpotifyResearch", when I try show 1 image in my grid is ok:

```
<Image x:Name="BigImage" Grid.Column="0" />
```

but when I try show collection of images, my program displays only ligth gray background:

```
            <ListView x:Name="ListOfImages" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background ="LightGray" Width="50" Height="50">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="150" Height="150" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Like this:
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ot1.png)

That is my xaml.cs script:

```
private async Task GetData(string id)
    {
        var data = await http.SerializeDataFromSingleAlbum(id);
        BigImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(data.images.FirstOrDefault().url));
        ListOfImages.ItemsSource = data.images;
        //TrackPlayer.Source = new Uri (data.tracks.items.FirstOrDefault().preview_url);
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us what exactly `data.images` is.

Comment: public class SingleAlbum
 {(...)
        public IList<Image> images { get; set; }
(...)}

Comment: My program didn't crashes but i have got issues in console window:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

Comment: `IList<Image>` doesn't mean than Image is `System.Windows.Controls.Image`? That would be totally wrong.

Comment: So what I should be do? I am rly newbie in WPF, my expirience with C# is less than half-year.

Comment: Bind to an `IList<ImageSource>` or some other collection type, e.g. an `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>`. Then add BitmapImage objects to the collection, and write `<Image Source="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: Side note: you set your images to be explicitly 150x150, but you put them in a container that is restricted to 50x50. That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: foreach (Image i in data.images)
            {
                ListOfImages = new BitmapImage(data.images[i].url);
            }

What is wrong with this code? I get validation "Can't convert "Image" to "int". But when I try 'foreach (int i in data.images)' i get that same validation (but before execute loop)